# Apache Royale : what is Jewel DataGrid rowHeight property equivalent on SDK 0.9.8#2556

Tags: datagrid, row-height, apache-royale

I moved from SDK 0.9.7 to SDK 0.9.8#2556 to be "up to date".
It seems that `rowHeight` property on Jewel Datagrid is no longuer available.
I didn't find how to set default row height. (I want all my row having 64 pixels height).

Does I need a bead or add an itemrenderer to set an height ?

Any help would be apprecied

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We removed APIs from TLC components that are available in PresentationModels to avoid duplicating APIs and add extra size.

This is an example from Tour De Jewel that uses rowHeigh` in DataGridPresentationModel:

```xml
<j:DataGrid localId="dg4" height="205"
    change="dataGridChange(event.target as DataGrid, lb4)"
    dataProvider="{productModel.productList}">
    <j:columns>
        <j:DataGridColumn label="Images" dataField="image" columnWidth="100" 
                        itemRenderer="itemRenderers.ImageDataGridItemRenderer"/>
        <j:DataGridColumn label="Title" dataField="title" columnWidth="140"/>
        <j:DataGridColumn label="Sales" dataField="sales" columnWidth="80" align="right"/>
    </j:columns>
    <j:beads>
        <j:DataGridPresentationModel rowHeight="54"/>
    </j:beads>
</j:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks a lot for your quick reply as usual. I use the bead and it works right  :)

Comment: What if i want to use variable rowHeight? how to set ?